# FullCalendar interpret TimeZone from RRule

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, rrule

I am currently using FullCalendar to display Events in the day-grid. There are both, events with just a single occurrence and with recurrency.

For the single occurences the start date is covered by moment-timezone conversion and displayed correctly in the Calendar which TimeZone I changed to "Europe/Amsterdam".

For the Recurring events I use the RRule-Plugin for FullCalendar.
A typical recurring event would look like this:

```
const calEv = {
   id: event.id,
   title: title,
   duration: "03:00",
   rrule: rrule
};
```

With the rrule like:

```
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,FR;DTSTART;TZID:Europe/Amsterdam=20200101T100000Z;UNTIL=20201231T130000Z"
```

The event will always be displayed from 10:00 am to 1:00 pm, no matter the TZID.
Is there a way for the calendar to use the timezone from the rrule?